# Pass variable from app.js to index.html

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i can successfully get data from the /api/session.json call and log it to my console.

how do i send the output of this api call to my index.html file and replace "Username"?

thanks!

here is my app.js file for my angular application:

```
'use strict';

var staticApp = angular.module('staticApp', [])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
      .when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'views/main.html',
        controller: 'MainCtrl'
      })
      .otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/'
      });
  }])
  .run( function($http) {
    $http.defaults.useXDomain = true;     

    // API CALL
    $http({method: 'GET', url: '/api/session.json'}).
      success(function(data, status, headers, config) {

        // THIS WORKS!!
        // MY CONSOLE SHOWS THIS:
        // Object {user: "devuser"}

        console.log(data); 

      }).
      error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log(status);
      });
  });
```

and here is my index.html fiile:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>  
  <head>
    <!-- meta and css stuff -->
  </head>
  <body ng-app="staticApp">
    <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <button type="button" 
                  class="btn btn-navbar" 
                  data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
          </button>
          <a class="brand" href="/">MyApp</a>
          <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
            <p class="navbar-text pull-right">

              <!-- I WANT Username TO BE THE VALUE RETURNED FROM THE API CALL -->

              Logged in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">Username</a>
            </p>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container" ng-view></div>

    <script src="scripts/vendor/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/app.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/controllers/main.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to add it to the $scope in a controller, then bind it to the DOM with braces  `{{username}}`. (Sorry no example code; typing on a tablet.)

Comment: can i define a controller within the .run method so that it is executed on every page?

Answer (score 1):

```
$scope.username = data
```

in your js file. (Assuming data is what is returned)

and in the html just do `{{username}}`

Comment: i added that line right after my console.log statement and get this error: "ReferenceError: $scope is not defined"

Comment: Can you pass the $scope as an arguemnt into your run. So normally you define the Controller in a separate js file and and pass the $scope variable in the constructor. But I notice that you have just one js file for both ur app and your controller. Its still fine ..

Comment: when i pass $scope as a param like this: .run( function($http, $scope)  i get this error: Uncaught Error: Unknown provider: $scopeProvider <- $scope

Answer (score 1):

Try passing in `$rootScope` (since that is where you technically are), then assign username on the `$rootScope`. Something like so:

```
function($http, $rootScope) {
  $rootScope.username = "Foo";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, you wouldn't have all of this logic within one glob. When you think about what you're doing in this small section of JS, you're:

- defining a module,
- matching URLs with templates and controllers,
- making a GET request,
- (logging in a user?),
- attempting to display the user's name in the HTML

You would be better off breaking this into chunks, with specific purposes.

Let's think about what you're trying to accomplish: you want your navbar to be aware of the user. To me, this sounds like an opportunity to use a controller.

#### index.html

```html
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="Navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <button type="button" 
              class="btn btn-navbar" 
              data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
      </button>
      <a class="brand" href="/">MyApp</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse collapse">
        <p class="navbar-text pull-right">
          Logged in as <a href="#" class="navbar-link">{{username}}</a>
        </p>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

#### scripts/controllers/Navbar.js

```js
staticApp.controller('Navbar', ['$scope', function ($scope) {
    $scope.username = 'Username!';
}]);
```

Now, we can provide a username to the `$scope` matching the `Navbar` template (`div.navbar` here). Of course, this isn't all that useful, since `Username!` is probably not everybody's username.

So, now our problem is: where can we put our code that handles logging in users from the server?

The perfect place for that is a service.

#### scripts/services/User.js

```js
staticApp.factory('User', ['$http', function ($http) {
  var User;

  var setUser = function (user) {
    if (angular.isObject(user))
      User = user;
  };

  var getUser = function () {
    if (angular.isObject(User))
      return User;
  };

  var logIn = function (username, password) {
    // $http call that validates the username and password.
    setUser({ user: username });
  };

  return {
    logIn: logIn,
    getUser: getUser
  };
}]);
```

The logic in this controller can be edited to match your flow, but it's not a bad idea to keep it modularized in this way. Exposing the `logIn` and `getUser` methods should be all your controllers will need.

Let's go back to the `Navbar` controller.

#### scripts/controllers/Navbar.js

```js
staticApp.controller('Navbar', ['$scope', 'User', function ($scope, User) {
    var user = User.getUser();

    $scope.username = user.username;
}]);
```

After you've configured the `User` service to work with your app's own user handling process, your app will be in a better position to grow. You don't have to mess with `$rootScope`, your templates can be bound to a controller (maybe the `Navbar` template will need some other functionality), and most importantly, your different concerns have been separated.

If you have any questions about anything I've changed above, let me know!

Comment: this is awesome! thanks. I am going with User as a service and then Navigation as a directive now. This response was indeed very helpful with getting me to start rethinkning this.